# How can create a case entity in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 using SOAP API?

Tags: soap, dynamics-crm

I'm having trouble creating a Case (aka Incident) entity using the MS Dynamics CRM 2013 SOAP API.  I think I've narrowed it down to a troublesome customerid a customeridtype related reference, but haven't been able to solve it despite quite a bit of research.

Here's the create XML I'm using:

```
<create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <entity>
        <b:attributes>
            <b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
                <c:key>customerid</c:key>
                <c:value i:type="b:EntityReference">
                    <b:id>a24fb802-557d-e411-a345-6c3be5a86468</b:id>
                    <b:logicalname>account</b:logicalname>
                    <b:name>Testing Account</b:name>
                </c:value>
            </b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
            <b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
                <c:key>new_email</c:key>
                <c:value i:type="d:string">test@domain.com</c:value>
            </b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
            <b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
                <c:key>new_phone</c:key>
                <c:value i:type="d:string">111-222-3333</c:value>
            </b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
            <b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
                <c:key>description</c:key>
                <c:value i:type="d:string">This is a test.  Please do not respond to this case.</c:value>
            </b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
            <b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
                <c:key>statuscode</c:key>
                <c:value i:type="b:OptionSetValue">
                    <b:value>1</b:value>
                </c:value>
            </b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
            <b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
                <c:key>prioritycode</c:key>
                <c:value i:type="b:OptionSetValue">
                    <b:value>2</b:value>
                </c:value>
            </b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
            <b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
                <c:key>new_date</c:key>
                <c:value i:type="d:dateTime">2014-12-06T09:56:00</c:value>
            </b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
            <b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
                <c:key>new_cstadmin</c:key>
                <c:value i:type="b:OptionSetValue">
                    <b:value>100000015</b:value>
                </c:value>
            </b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
            <b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
                <c:key>title</c:key>
                <c:value i:type="d:string">Test Case by XYZ</c:value>
            </b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
            <b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
                <c:key>subjectid</c:key>
                <c:value i:type="b:EntityReference">
                    <b:id>41b106d1-074a-e411-b697-9cb654957388</b:id>
                </c:value>
            </b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
        </b:attributes>
        <b:logicalname>incident</b:logicalname>
    </entity>
</create>
```

When I submit this, I get an **HTTP-500** back, with the error,

> You should specify a parent contact or account

I assume that means that this chunk of xml...

```
            <b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
                <c:key>customerid</c:key>
                <c:value i:type="b:EntityReference">
                    <b:id>a24fb802-557d-e411-a345-6c3be5a86468</b:id>
                    <b:logicalname>account</b:logicalname>
                    <b:name>Testing Account</b:name>
                </c:value>
            </b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
```

...does not adequately reference the parent account for the case.  So I assume my syntax is incorrect somehow.   The reason I choose this syntax is that it reflects the same form that is returned when I RETRIEVE a case.

I've also tried a slightly different syntax by preparing "customerid" and "customeridtype" attributes as separate key-value pairs, such as:

```
        <b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
            <c:key>customeridtype</c:key>
            <c:value i:type="d:string">account</c:value>
        </b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
        <b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
            <c:key>customerid</c:key>
            <c:value i:type="b:EntityReference">
                <b:id>a24fb802-557d-e411-a345-6c3be5a86468</b:id>
            </c:value>
        </b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
```

...but still, no dice.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How are you creating this XML?

Comment: I'm using a cloud-to-cloud platform service - itDuzzit - to put this together.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `customerid` and `customeridtype` should both be there (because of the special "customer" field structure) so I'd try to mix your two attempts:

```
<b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
    <c:key>customerid</c:key>
    <c:value i:type="b:EntityReference">
        <b:id>a24fb802-557d-e411-a345-6c3be5a86468</b:id>
        <b:logicalname>account</b:logicalname>
        <b:name>Testing Account</b:name>
    </c:value>
</b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
<b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
    <c:key>customeridtype</c:key>
    <c:value i:type="d:string">1</c:value>
</b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
```

Note that `customeridtype` contains the type code as a number in my attempt

```
<c:value i:type="d:string">1</c:value>
```

That said, as a side note, if you can make it so your data comes out as JSON you could POST it to the OData service (resulting in a less painful experience).

Comment: A good thought, however i'm still getting the same error " when I try this technique "You should specify a parent contact or account."  And I agree that the OData service would possibly more transparent, but it's not an option for me at this point, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The Customer field is a really special one so, rather than passing an EntityReference to the account, try to pass a "b:Customer" object instead and see if works?

Also, don´t waste time generating the request manually, use SDK tools like [Sdk.Soap.js](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SdkSoapjs-9b51b99a) for SOAP or the REST endpoint (much simpler).